# Asp.net core webapi entityframework how to query distinct and not in

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have the following sql query and would like to write in entityframework linq. Can anyone help me how to write this. Basically i want the unique tag names from a table and also not already added for the given user.

Expected sql query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(source.tagName) tagName FROM [dbo].[UserTag] source
WHERE source.tagName IS NOT NULL AND source.tagName NOT IN (
  SELECT tagName FROM [dbo].[UserTag] WHERE userid=87 AND tagName IS NOT NULL
)
```

Current linq query:

```
var list = await _context.UserTag
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(userTag => userTag.TagName != null && !userTag.Disabled)
            .Select(userTag => userTag.TagName)
            .OrderBy(tagName => tagName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Does your Linq give different results than SQL query? It seems to me your LINQ is good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Except for "not in"

```
var answer = list1.Except(list2);
```

For example in your code, you can write something like this:

```
var blackList = await _context.UserTag
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(userTag => userTag.TagName != null && !userTag.Disabled && userTag.userid = 87)
            .Select(userTag => userTag.TagName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToListAsync();

var list = await _context.UserTag
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(userTag => userTag.TagName != null)
            .Select(userTag => userTag.TagName)
            .OrderBy(tagName => tagName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToListAsync();

var finalList = list.Except(blackList);
```

Second approach:

```
var blackList = _context.UserTag
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(userTag => userTag.TagName != null && !userTag.Disabled && userTag.userid = 87)
            .Select(userTag => userTag.TagName);

var list = _context.UserTag
            .AsNoTracking()
            .Where(userTag => userTag.TagName != null)
            .Select(userTag => userTag.TagName)
            .OrderBy(tagName => tagName)
            .Distinct();

var finalList = await (list.Except(blackList)).ToListAsync();;
```

Third approach;

```
var query =    
    from u in _context.UserTag   
    where !(from uu in _context.UserTag 
            where uu.TagName != null && uu.userid = 87)
            select uu.TagName)    
           .Contains(u.TagName)    
    select u.UserTag;

var finalList = query.OrderBy(tagName => tagName)
            .Distinct()
            .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks. But in this case the database is hit two times to get the result right? is there a way to use as single query

Comment: @MukilDeepthi I think the "Except" will also work on IQueryable, I write a sample code in the answer just test it, also you can write a link query as an alternative approach

Comment: @MukilDeepthi see the third approach

Comment: the third answer worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can be achieved using `Contains()` method as well:

```
var exceptionList = (from source in _context.UserTag
            where source.userid.Equals(87) && source.tagName!=null)
            order by source.tagName
            select source.tagname).Distint();

var result = from source in _context.UserTag
        where source.tagname != null && (!exceptionList.Contains(source.tagname != null))
        order by source.tagname
        select source.tagname).Distint();
```